# rosjava builds fail, says I'm missing ant, but I'm not

Tags: ros, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had typed up a long explanation, but the webpage did something weird and I lost it.

Anyway, I have two machines, a desktop and laptop, both running linuxmint 12. The desktop installed correctly and works well with rosjava. The laptop always fails during builds. I have installed rosjava several different ways (including the exact method used on the dekstop machine from which I took notes during installation.) I also tried installing rosjava-core from synaptic, and following this tutorial, except using electric instead of diamondback.: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/courses/int-robot/2011/notes/install.php

All of my builds fail when they run ant. If I run rosmake rosjava -rosdep--install, I get the following:

```
Failed to find rosdep ant for package rosjava on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
Failed to find rosdep boost for package rosjava on OS:ubuntu version:11.10
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed
```

When I run my package I get the following:

```
  ...BUILD FAILED
  /home/embedded/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/build.xml:42: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  
  Total time: 4 seconds
  Executing command: ['ant'] ...
```

ANT IS INSTALLED.

```
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on August 19 2011
```

I even copied the exact same (working) package from the working machine to the laptop, and got the same failures.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out over this thing. Meanwhile, I'll be looking for a more appropriate tool to work on this laptop...  Like a large hammer.

Here is my package:[my_package.tar.gz.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13273916543090887.jpg)

Oh, and I have the correct bootstrap line in the Makefile.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12728/rosjava-builds-fail,-says-i%27m-missing-ant,-but-i%27m-not./) by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep error is not critical, it just means that the ROS doesn't know about the correct package for your Ubuntu version. Just compile without the --rosdep-install flag, i.e `rosmake rosjava`. To me the error doesn't look like an the system cannot find ant, I don't see anything like `ant missing` when you are compiling. In particular the message says that the error happens in an ant file which indicates that ant was actually called.

After calling rosmake once on your package, you can directly call ant to just compile it. Did you try that? Also, you didn't paste the compiler error output which might really help.

Your current code will not compile against current rosjava. Rosjava has been refactored a lot over the last few weeks and the NodeMain interface changed. DefaultNodeFactory is gone, too.

EDIT:
The output definitely shows a problem when compiling rosjava:

```
...
[javac] RosoutLogger.java:188: package org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs does not exist
[javac]       publish(org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs.Log.FATAL, message);
[javac]                                            ^
[javac] RosoutLogger.java:196: package org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs does not exist
[javac]       publish(org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs.Log.FATAL, message, t);
[javac]                                            ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 24 errors
```

Some of the required messages could not be found. There is a certain chance that the following steps could work:

1. Check that rosgraph_msgs is installed on your system: '`rospack find rosgraph_msgs`' should print a path.
2. Remove all build relicts from previous rosjava builds:

   rm -rf ~/.ros/rosjava
3. Rebuild everything:

   rosmake --pre-clean rosjava

Now, the compiler shouldn't complain anymore. However, your package isn't built yet. You can try compiling it with '`rosmake my_package`'. With your current code, this will fail however because your package uses a deprecated rosjava API.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2012-01-24**:
Here is my bash output: http://www.pastie.org/3245781  and here is the log file: http://www.pastie.org/3245797  I've been trying things in the time between my post, so this log file is slightly different than before.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-24**:
Can you please post the complete error output?

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2012-01-24**:
I've tried compiling without -rosdep--install, but it still fails. I removed the code in the src folder and tried rosmake my_package. This failed exactly the same as before. I started from scratch using the tutorial on the rosjava page with the same results as well.